# Make all children the same height inside a flexBox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, blueprintjs, rebass

I have a flexBox which has 2 children. 1 child is just an icon and it doesnt seem to take up the same height as the other child. Please advice me on a way to fix this.

Playground URL:[URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-swirles-2s2s5?file=/src/App.js:0-2133)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
import { Button, Card, Colors, Icon } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { IconNames } from "@blueprintjs/icons";
import { Box, Flex } from "@rebass/grid";
import cx from "classnames";

const CustomIcon = styled(Button)`
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <Flex>
      <Box width={"90%"}>
        <Card
          interactive={true}
          className={cx({ selected: true, muted: true })}
        >
          <Flex alignItems="center">
            <Box mr={2} css={{ minWidth: 0 }}>
              Sample
            </Box>
            <Box flex="auto" />
            <Box flex="none">
              <CustomIcon
                className="utility-button"
                icon={<Icon icon={IconNames.EDIT} />}
                minimal={true}
                title="Edit scenario"
              />
              <CustomIcon
                className="utility-button"
                icon={<Icon icon={IconNames.DUPLICATE} />}
                minimal={true}
                title="Copy scenario"
              />
              <CustomIcon
                className="utility-button"
                icon={<Icon icon={IconNames.DOCUMENT_SHARE} />}
                minimal={true}
                title={"Transfer"}
              />
              <CustomIcon
                className="utility-button"
                icon={<Icon icon={IconNames.TRASH} color={Colors.RED1} />}
                minimal={true}
                title="Delete scenario"
              />
            </Box>
          </Flex>
        </Card>
      </Box>
      <Box width={"10%"}>
        <Card>
          <Icon icon={IconNames.CHEVRON_RIGHT} />
        </Card>
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  );
}

export default styled(App)`
  &.selected {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #137cbd, inset 0 -1px 0 #137cbd,
      inset 1px 0 0 #137cbd;
  }
  &.muted {
    opacity: 0.5;
    .utility-button {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
  &:not(:hover):not(.selected) {
    .utility-button {
      opacity: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
`;
```

This is my result:

[image]

I want the second child to be as the same height as the first child. Please advice.

Comment: Fixed it by adding the utility class. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first of all, your icons should be the same size,
2. set the width and height of the icon wrapper layer,
3. reset the icon's `line-height`.

```css
.utility-button{
  flex: none;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
}

.utility-button .icon {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to explicitly set the height of the elements in your CSS - ie. `sampleDiv { height: 20px )`. Also the padding on the left element could be greater than the right, causing its display size to be larger.

Comment: I dont explocitly set the height on the flexBox or on the child. I tried alignItems:stretch and didnt work as well. Any other workarounds?